# How to get real inverse kinematic locations WRT to end-effector

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, beginner here

I am making a custom manipulator and I was wondering if there is a package or some sort of library I could use to find inverse kinematic locations of an object in the world with respect to the endeffector and base_link, please give list the sensors I will need and how to execute it, thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285525/how-to-get-real-inverse-kinematic-locations-wrt-to-end-effector./) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you're looking for it [moveit](http://moveit.ros.org/) the ROS manipulator planning and control package. This can be used to simulate, plan and control an arm. As a part of that when a manipulator has been configured you can use this to perform inverse kinematics.

Can you explain a little more about the problem you're trying to solve?

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on 2018-03-16**:
I am making a 4dof arm and I, for now, I am simulating it with Moveit. What don't I understand is how will I code for the servo motors in the real arm? I am making this project on Arduino if that helps. thanks for the help.